# Reading and Sending Values to a 104 pc I/O relay board

Tags: input

I am wondering how to send values to a 104 PC I/O board. There are several on the market that use a similar approach. Information surrounding the one I have in my possession can be found [here](http://www.dpie.com/pc104/r104.html). I have the R104-88 model(8 inputs and 8 outputs). From my understanding I have to select which base address I want to use with the jumpers. Using the jumpers I have selected the base address to be 300H.  So if I were to read 302H I would be getting the inputs from pins 0, 1 , 2, and 3. The problem is that not matter what the inputs are, I always read FFH from address 302H. I am using [inpout32.dll](http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/Inpout32.dll_for_Windows_98/2000/NT/XP.html) to read the addresses. The code I am using to do this using python is below. I am running Windows XP as my OS.

```
import ctypes
print ctypes.windll.inpout32.Inp32(0x302)
```

Is there a better way do this? What am I missing? Do I have to configure the Hardware some how? I am at a loss of what to try next. Apologies if this is not the correct forum to ask. The question kinda falls under electronics, stackover flow and super user.

Edit:

The setup I am using is a 104 PC. The I/O board just fits on top of the 104pc and power supply.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your setup?  Processor board, number of boardss, anything?

Answer (score 1):

In the old days, you could hold a scope probe or (my favorite) audible logic probe on the select output of the '138 decode chip, and hear it fire when you hit the right address, or at least hear it fire more frequently if you wrote a tight loop with debug to just read the address over and over again...  but with the CPLD on there the decode signal is probably buried inside.

You could approach the output side first - you can write a program to try toggling the relays at all of the possible addresses.  Though it appears the input and output sides have separate address selection?

You could also test your software against another I/O device, for example reading the status lines of a (true ISA bus hardware, not USB) parallel port, either on the PC104 system if it has one, or a different vintage PC...

You might also simply have a bad board or an address conflict with another module - do try putting the board at a different address.

Comment: Writing to all the address it could be could do really strange things - You might change the behavior of lots of pieces of hardware that are on the same bus. I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: It might be a good idea to disconnect any real world hardware first, and power cycle after as there's a small chance of introducing instability, but systems of that age are pretty resilient hardware wise.  If faced between the choice of not accomplishing my project vs. the .01% chance of damaging the equipment that wasn't currently useful to my project, I'd take it.